# Check Asp.Net log files

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, logging

We have a web application running on our web server, however in one particular page, a link appears to be broken. Nothing is apparent the code so the creator of the application has asked me to check the log files to see if that can give us any clues.

Can someone point me in the right direction as to how I would check the log files?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

logs files could show up in a few places. Your web traffic will show up where defined in your IIS configuration (default is c:\windows\system32\logfiles\[application id]\ ). .net error codes show up in your event viewer (start > run > eventvwr) under applications. You may also have some custom logging which is stored some place else.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're running your application on IIS, and that the link is not to an external site, you could look at the IIS log file, which by default, records a line for every request made to the server.  A missing link should probably result in a line in the log file with status 404.

To find the location of the log file (in IIS 7) open IIS Manager and expand the tree view to see the node corresponding to your website.  In the main panel, open the "Logging" item whcih should show you the directory.  This is typically `%SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\LogFiles` but I've also seen it as `%SystemDrive%\Windows\System32\LogFiles`.

A useful tool for interrogating the (sometimes incomprehensible) IIS log files is [LogParser](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=890cd06b-abf8-4c25-91b2-f8d975cf8c07&displaylang=en), available from Microsoft.